# Convert a String to AnyVal based on some other specification in Scala

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I have a service which will return me a XML file as data, and there is also a schema of the data.

```
<RECORD>
    <PROP_VAL NAME="name"><VAL>Tim</VAL></PROP_VAL>
    <PROP_VAL NAME="age"><VAL>13</VAL></PROP_VAL>
</RECORD>
```

There is specification of each property what type of data it would contain, and hence I can "safely" convert age to Int.
Now, what I am looking for is a small architecture which can help me to convert a String value based on the specification.

```
trait PropertyValue(name: String, value: String) {
    // this is a PROP_VAL I got from the XML file. And now I have a list of these objects of type PropertyValue.
    def v: T
}
```

The question is how do I design and implement a type hierarchy to extend from PropertyValue when I do PropertyValue("age", "13) I got something like IntPropVal.

```
class IntPropertyValue extends PropertyValue {
}
object PropertyValue {
    def apply(name: String, value: Value): PropertyValue // should return the concrete type
}
```

Several techniques that I can think of are Abstract type member, implicit convert?  Am I on the right direction?

Comment: Are you trying to build something general, or you are working on a specific integration, and parameters will be always the same? ... In other words: what is your domain: xml manipulation or some specific business problem/domain.

Comment: @michaJlS it is for specific domain. The main purpose is not for XML manipulation, but consume this specific format of XML.

Comment: Do you have a lot of different entities to decode?

Comment: @michaJlS no and yes. There is no domain entity, but there is concept of it, there is a thing called record, which is the same structure as the XML, and it contains a list of property values. Those values will be explained by a schema definition which I will know when I load the record from XML. What I want is when I create concrete object/class for each record property, I assign right value object.

Comment: I’d like to make it common , hence it needs to support any model that needs to be converted.